# Нахождение минора элемента матрицы

Tags: c++, математика, матрицы

Цикличная конструкция крива, не выводит миноры элементов матрицы уже после первого.
Т.е. получается, что находит минор лишь одного первого элемента.
У нас есть двумерный массив 3х3 на `i` строк и `j` столбцов.
Беру индексы каждого элемента, а затем сравниваю с ними индексы всех прочих элементов. Нам нужно получить все элементы, не лежащие в строке и столбце конкретного элемента. И повторить для каждого из 9 элементов. Таким образом, должно получиться 9 миноров. Например, для элемента `A(11)` минором будет определитель элементов `A(22)`, `A(23)`, `A(32)` и `A(33)`. Для простоты я решил записывать эти 4 элемента в одномерный массив `Temp[4]`, вычислять минор, выводить, а затем повторять для следующего элемента. Вывод только для первого элемента.

```
int Temp[4], k, Tempi, Tempj;
for (i=0; i<3; i++){
    Tempi = i;
    for (j=0; i<3; i++){
        Tempj = j;
        for (i=0; i<3; i++){
            for (j=0; j<3; j++){
                if (i!=Tempi && j!=Tempj){
                    Temp[k]=Mat[i][j];
                    k++;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (k=0; k<4; k++){
            cout << Temp[k] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << Temp[3]*Temp[0]-Temp[1]*Temp[2] << endl; // тут вычисляется сам минор
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас k не инциализирован, страно как программа не крешиться. Видимо где-то k надо сбрасывать на 0

Comment: И во втором цикле **for (j=0; i<3; i++){**  вас явно подвел копи-паст, потому что должно быть видимо **for (j=0; j<3; j++){**

Comment: Да и счётчики циклов `i` и `j` используются как в двух внешних, так и в двух внутренних циклах - нехорошо. Также `k` нужно инициализировать нулём перед двумя внутренними циклами.

Comment: Копипаст не причем, извините. Это моя невнимательность подвела. К инициализировался, однако когда вносил правки, переписал и не вошло в финальную версию. Спасибо.